# Prolog. How to print encoded a matrix?

Tags: prolog

I have the next matrix:

```
map(1,[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
       [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
       [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]).
```

I want to print this matrix like this:
   -if the matrix element value is 0 -> print('~') 
   -if the matrix element value is 1 -> print('#').

I tried to do this, but my method print false everytime. This is my code:

```
print_encoded([H|T]) :-
   H==0 ->
   write('~');
   H==1 ->
   write('#');
   print_encoded(T).

showEncoded :-
    map(_,Map),
    print_encoded(Map).
```

Maybe this is a easy question, but prolog is a new programming language for me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no base case for [] for print_encoded.
It could be

```
print_encoded([])  :-
   nl.
```

You can use a "functional spirit" with module lambda of SWI-Prolog

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

print_encoded(M) :-
    maplist(\X^(maplist(\Y^(Y = 0
                            -> write('~')
                            ;  write('#')),
                       X),
               nl),
           M).
```

Answer (score 0):

maplist seems has been built on purpose of such tasks...

```
encode_map(M) :- maplist(maplist(encode_cell), M).
encode_cell(0) :- write('~').
encode_cell(1) :- write('#').
```